# Error using the same JSX Component when imported on declared inline

Tags: javascript, react-router, reactjs, redux

I've got a simple [redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux) boilerplate project and I'm experiencing different behaviour when I import a top level (smart) component compared to if I inline the class declaration.

Creating the class causes no errors however when I extract the class to a separate file I receive the following error:

```
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `routerState` was not specified in `AppContainer`. Check the render method of `RoutingContext`.
```

I have tried inlining the entire file and the error goes away

```
// == Import ==================================================================
import AppContainer from '../containers/App.jsx';
// === Declare Inline =========================================================
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';


@connect(state => ({ routerState: state.router }))
class AppContainer extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    routerState: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xs-12">
            <h1>App</h1>
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
// ============================================================================
```

Here is the [project repo](https://github.com/rockingskier/redux-routing-context-error/) (its super striped back).

```
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^1.12.5",
    "react": "^0.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "^1.0.0-rc3",
    "redux": "^3.0.2",
    "redux-router": "^1.0.0-beta3"
  },
```

Comment: Very strange, I will pull down your repo and have a look

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand it's because you have said that the `propTypes` children and routerState are to be expected, yet you haven't used them as propTypes when using the component, as you are passing the App component as a propType into the `<Route />` component.

```
<Route path="/" component={AppContainer}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home} />
</Route>
```

I am not sure if your App component should have these propTypes, as you can't pass them in. However you should be able to retrieve `this.props.children` by changing that propType to `PropTypes.node`.

You can pass props into your router components by doing:

```
<Route path="myComponent/:name" component={MyComponent} />
```

Where 'name' is the param you want, and do:
`this.props.params.name` within 'MyComponent'

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I can access `this.props.children` fine however I am unable to access anything from the `state`. The `@connect` decorator on the `App` component should allow me to pass in any attributes on `state`.  This works if I define the class in `routes.jsx` but not if I import the same code into the same place in `routes.jsx`

Comment: Have you tried using the basic examples on their repo? And comparing?

Comment: Copying their example (https://github.com/rackt/redux-router/blob/master/examples/basic/index.js) into my `index.jsx` work and I get the same error if I move their `App` to a separate file.  I can only assume I am doing something stupid somewhere.  I can't actually run their example directly, I've forked and `npm i`ed in all three folders and it complains that it cant reference `redux-router` (itself).

Comment: It's strange, I feel it's just because you are using another contextType on your app that is expected and not fulfilled, and that isn't in the example, and in addition you should change your propType to node like I suggeested

Comment: I'm adding a PropType, not a ContextType.  The `connect` in the second file doesn't actually run the function passed to it.